# pypi package published but can't download

Tags: python, package, pypi

I have here a package on pypi that was published by command line, but no-one can download it (except on the laptop I packaged it up on):

```
pip install webdriver_chauffeur
Collecting webdriver_chauffeur
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement webdriver_chauffeur (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for webdriver_chauffeur


pip install webdriver-chauffeur
Collecting webdriver-chauffeur
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement webdriver-chauffeur (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for webdriver-chauffeur
```

[image]

It is here https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=pkg_edit&name=webdriver_chauffeur

Pretty sure I followed this one https://axiacore.com/blog/basic-steps-publish-python-package/

Why is this package not installable?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Dozens of people have the same issue, it seems pypi isn't stable and you should run your own pip server to use your packages

Answer (score 1):

I maintain a package on pypi and just hit this issue. I resolved it by hitting "update release" on the pypi version page of my package. If this problem persists you might consider letting the package maintainer know about the workaround.

Comment: try making a single change (hide/unhide something), then update again?

Comment: does not work. very disappointing this is a huge hassle when building multiple python projects. is there a working alternative to pypi for listing on pip?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread, but I ran into a similar issue and this thread popped up on Google.

I faced the same error message. The problem was, that I set a Python version constraint of >=3.9. because that's the version I develop in. However, the environment where I tried to run `pip install <...>` was using Python 3.7. By relaxing the constraint in `setup.py` (or `pyproject.toml` in my case) the issue was resolved.